# SharePoint Online Custom List

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, custom-list

I followed this guide http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/angularjs-in-sharepoint-2013-part-1/ on creating an AngularJS with the use of the script editor but when I completed the code and submitted the form, It says: "Request failed, Column "LastName" does not exist".

I did create a list which consists of First Name, Last Name, and Address but it still doesn't read it.

Is there anything I did wrong in the guide?

Comment: I have solved the issue. Apparently, when I opened up InfoPath, The Column LastName is called: Last_x0020_name. I am not sure why it created this name though when I specifically name it "Last Name".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your List Settings Page. Click on the "LastName" field you had created. Notice the URL to find the internal name of the field. The URLwill something like "http://...Field=[InternalName]" . This will give you the field name that you can use to access the field.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It's very useful as I dont have to open Infopath all the time.